# Runtime Error with Vim Omnicompletion

Tags: python, vim, autocomplete, runtime-error

I was trying to use Vim's omnicompletion with my Python code, but whenever I try C-x + C-o, it prompts the following error message:

> Runtime Error!
>
> Program E:\Vim\vim73\gvim.exe
>
> R6034
> An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly.
> Please contact the application's support team for more information.

Could anybody please tell me how to solve this problem!  Many many thanks!

Answer (score 22):

I have the same issue which cause by gvim not able to load python pyd dll. There are some tips to solve the .pyd dll which cause the above issue. I'm not sure is there any way to solve the Runtime Error for all dll.
Refere to [Not embed the correct manifest for the msvc runtimes on windows](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/issues/detail?id=214) link on how to solve your issue.

Update:
Instead of updating manifest for the .pyd file. I tried to update manifest for gvim directly by updating the original gvim manifest with some changes from python.exe manifest.

```
# dump manifest from gvim.exe
>> mt.exe -inputresource:gvim.exe;#1 -out:gvim.manifest

# dump manifest from python.exe
# *I use python26 for gvim, default gvim come with python27
>> mt.exe -inputresource:c:\python26\python.exe;#1 -out:python.manifest

# manually edit gvim.manifest, just change the line with dependentAssembly with
# line from the python.manifest which will depend on VC90.CRT
# Then, update the edited manifest into gvim.exe
>> mt.exe -manifest gvim.manifest -outputresource:gvim.exe;1
```

Below are my edited gvim.manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <assemblyIdentity processorArchitecture="*" version="7.3.0.0" type="win32" name="Vim"></assemblyIdentity>
  <description>Vi Improved - A Text Editor</description>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC90.CRT" version="9.0.21022.8" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"></assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>

  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>

  <asmv3:application>
    <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
      <dpiAware>true</dpiAware>
    </asmv3:windowsSettings>
  </asmv3:application>
</assembly>
```

Comment: +1 It's ridiculous that it had to come to this, but this fixed the problem.

Comment: Due to my environment, I had a lot of struggles getting vim and python to play nicely together.  Modifying the manifest for gvim as mentioned above totally solved my problem.  I would not have thought of this.  Thanks!

Comment: still valid in 2015 for vim74

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem (Windows 7) and I could solve it by removing paths from my PATH variable that contain `msvcr90.dll`.

After removing several entries the error stopped popping up. Unfortunately I didn't make a note of which entries I removed. But It was `C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenVPN\bin` and several others including Windows Live.

I got the hint about looking for the problem in the path from here (bottom of the page): https://bitbucket.org/Haroogan/vim-youcompleteme-for-windows/src

Comment: Thanks for your solution.In my case it was cmake that I installed recently :)

Comment: Thanks @Maciek for mentioning that, it was cmake in my case as well. I simply deleted the runtime dlls from its directory since it is installed on my system so there is no need to keep it there.

Comment: Thanks so much! I had msvcr90.dll in my working directory that was causing me this issue.

Comment: This worked for me. Semantic cloud endpoint protection or some jazz like that had this in my path for some inexplicable reason.